# Stopping Multiline Text for buttons in an AlertDialog

Tags: android

I have an alert dialog where users enter text with an OK and a Cancel button. It looks fine when I test on a tablet, but on my phone the Cancel text on the button is broken onto two lines:
Can
cel

There looks like there is enough room on my phone, but the text is broken up. I know how to fix this on a normal button, but when I tried alert.getButton to get the button the alert stops showing up all together. Here is the code I tried:

Here's my code:

```
final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
      final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
      input.setText(existingName);
      alert.setView(input);        
      alert.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

              //do stuff here
          }
      });

      alert.setButton2("Cancel",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      dialog.cancel();
                  }
              });
      alert.getButton(1).setMaxLines(1);
      alert.show();
```

Comment: Check if it is null using : if(alert.getButton(1)==null) Log.v("NNN","NNNN");

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out it is null, so now I have to figure out how to call the function correctly.

Comment: check my answer (: sorry for late answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok change

```
alert.getButton(1).setMaxLines(1);
```

to

```
alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON2).setMaxLines(1);
```

Comment: I got the same problem: but this does not work at all. No matter what ID I give to this method, I get null.

Answer (score 1):

The valid parameters for `AlertDialog.getButton(Integer)` are

```
DialogInterface.BUTTON1
DialogInterface.BUTTON2
DialogInterface.BUTTON3
DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE
DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL
DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE
```

The first 3 are depreciated, so it's recommended you set your button using this method:

```
public void setButton(int whichButton,
                      CharSequence text,
                      DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

Where `whichButton` is one of the bottom 3 options above.